# Open all files from list simultaneously

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need to modify a (*variable* but small) number of files, and I wonder if there is a Python syntax that would allow me to open them in a `with` statement. E.g. something like

```
file_names = ("file_a", "file_b", "file_c")

with open(file_names) as files:
    for file_ in files:
         file_.write("Hello file!")
```

The length of `file_names` in this example will vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) does support such syntax:

```
with open("file_a", "r+") as fa, open("file_b", "r+") as fb, \
        open("file_c", "r+") as fc:
    for f in (fa, fb, fc):
        f.write("Hello file!")
```

To use `with` on a variable number of context managers, you would need at least Python 3.3 and [`contextlib.ExitStack`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).

Comment: Just to note you're going to need to open the files with some form of write access for `.write` to work...